# How to join two variables together to create a username?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to join the two variables together to create a username?

```
name = input("enter name: ")
age = int(input("enter age: "))
username = (name[0,3] + str(age))
print(username)
```

This gives me a `type error` but I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong. I want the first three letters of the name to be joined with the age to form a new username. Can someone please help me!

Comment: what is your expected output? can you be precise?

Comment: if the name i input is emily and my age 15 then i want my ouput to be emi15

Comment: `username= (name[:3] + str(age))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `username = (name[0,3]+str(age))` raises exception because of this part : `name[0,3]`

You can not use comma while indexing strings. Use `name[0:3]`, or basically `name[:3]` instead.

And then, your code becomes `username = (name[:3] + str(age))`.

Note : Also you don't need the outer parenthesis in `username = (name[:3] + str(age))`.